# how does cypress locate element in iframe

Tags: iframe, cypress

It doesn't work at **cy.wrap($doc.find("#input")).type("test", { force: true })**: CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: 'undefined', but never found it.

```
it('iframe - check it', function () {
    cy.visit("https://jsfiddle.net/1w9jpnxo/1/");
    cy.get("iframe[name='result']").then($iframe => {

        const $doc = $iframe.contents();
        cy.wrap($doc.find("#input")).type("test", { force: true });
        //cy.wrap($doc.find("#submit")).click({ force: true });
    });
})
```

*"cypress": "^3.8.3"*

Above is the common practice in internet but it doesn't work for me.

I also read through the open proposal on https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html?#How-do-I-test-elements-inside-an-iframe but cannot understand what the solution is.

Comment: You can check my answer in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605596/cypress-run-test-in-iframe/57609872#57609872). 

Iframes in Cypress are tricky but there's a workaround which worked for me to evaluating element's visibility within an iframe. Not sure if it''ll work also for interacting with elements but you can try.

Comment: @DurkoMatko Appreciated! Could you please share the code how you locate the element like an input in iframe? I cannot try your solution for now but I cannot wait. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After you add a helper function to your `cypress/support/commands.js` as I describe in my answer here ([Cypress - run test in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605596/cypress-run-test-in-iframe/57609872#57609872)), you can evaluate whether the input exists with:

```js
cy.get('#iframe-id')
  .iframe('body #yourInputId')
  .should('exist')
```

I'm not sure whether typing into it will work, but you can definitely try:

```js
cy.get('#iframe-id')
  .iframe('body #yourInputId')
  .type('test text')
```

Let me know if it worked, I'm curious myself..