# Find element inside Iframe fails in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to click an element inside frame. When i use  cy.wrap i get Error 
"  **Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '[name="border_top"].contents() body #acceptInvitation', but never found it.**

Code

```
   it('Automate C# Corner Page', function() {  
    cy.get('[name="border_top"]').then(function ($iframe) {
    const doc = $iframe.contents().find('body')
   // doc.find('#acceptInvitation').click({force:true})
    cy.wrap(doc.find('#acceptInvitation')).click({force:true})

   })
```

[image: Element to be clicked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add a helper function to your `cypress/support/commands.js` as I describe in my answer here ([Cypress - run test in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605596/cypress-run-test-in-iframe/57609872#57609872)), you can evaluate whether the button exists with:

```js
cy.get('#iframe-id')
  .iframe('body #yourButtonId')
  .should('exist')
```

I think clicking the element in the iframe could be done like this.

```js
cy.get('#iframe-id')
  .iframe('body #yourButtonId')
  .click({force:true})
```

Comment: To this custom command how do we accept an alert that comes from an iframe @DurkoMatko

Comment: On clicking button(acceptInvitation)  in iframe i get an alert box (with ok and cancel options). Cypress doesnt auto accept alerts that comes from iframe

Comment: Uff, here I can't help, never had to solve similar issue before. Srry.

Comment: cy.get('#iframe-id')
  .iframe('body #yourButtonId')
  .click({force:true}) this will never work, because here you are just clicking on ifarme, the ask here is to click webelement which itself inside an ifarme.

Answer (score 0):

****install cypress-iframe()****

import cypress-iframe in the file

```
 cy.iframe().find('selector');
```

Comment: Please read my answers, it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare one method into base js file like shown below:

```
getIframeBody() {
        return cy
            .get('object')
            .its('0.contentDocument').
            its('body')
            .then(cy.wrap)
    };
```

Then use this method as:

```
getIframeBody().find("cssLocater).click(); OR getIframeBody().xpath("xpath).click();
```

This will work for sure.