# How do you select elements in a frame (not iframe) using Cypress? AssertionError

Tags: iframe, cypress, frame

I have seen posts such as
[Cypress - run test in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605596/cypress-run-test-in-iframe/57609872#57609872) for how to handle *iframes* in Cypress. But I am using the old and outdated ***frames***, which is what a legacy system (that I have to test) uses.

I have checked [Github -Cypress iframes](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/685) which is recommended by Cypress, but haven't found an answer for plain old frames. Using the solution for iframe, hasn't worked.

The problem is the same as with an iframe where, when trying to select an element using

```
cy.get('input').type('test');
```

you receive an **AssertionError** stating:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: input, but never found it.
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with `<frame>`, but testing on this source

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Example page</title>
</head>

<frameset cols="150,*">
  <frame src="example_a.html">
  <frame src="example_b.html">
  <noframes>
    <body>
      <p>Alternate content</p>
    </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>

</html>
```

**example_b.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Example page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input />
</body>

</html>
```

this test works

```js
cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html')  // served from vscode

cy.get('frame')
  .eq(1)                                     // 2nd frame
  .then($frame => $frame[0].contentWindow)   // it's window
  .its('document.body')                      
  .within(() => {                  // sets cy.root() to 2nd frame body
    cy.get('input')
      .type('something')
      .invoke('val')
      .should('eq', 'something')
  })
```

If you've got more complicated stuff to do, you can try visiting the frame's source, for example this makes the frame content the top window

```js
cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/example_b.html')

cy.get('input')
  .type('something')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'something')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
cy.get('#iframeSelector')
       .then(($iframe) => {
            const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')

                cy.wrap($body)
                    .find('input')
                    .type('test')
            });
```

Comment: @Micah has `<frame>` not `<iframe>`.